# Label ends with ''..." in javafx 1.0

Tags: string, javafx, javafx-1

I put a string in a variabele and used it as text in a label. This works for shorter text, but my text is a few sentences long, so it ends with `...` instead of finishing my string. I'm working with JavaFX 1.0. Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Edit:
This is the code I wrote. I put the variable `HandleidingDobbelsteen` in a stage in an other file.

```
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

package var DobbelsteenHandleiding = Label {
    text: "Hier komt te staan wat de uitkomst van de dobbelsteen betekent."
    translateX: 830
    translateY: 245
    width: 140
    textWrap: true;
}

package var HandleidingDobbelsteen = Group {
    content:[
        DobbelsteenHandleiding,
        Rectangle {
            x: 825, y: 220
            width: 150, height: 120
            fill: null
            stroke: Color.BLACK
            strokeWidth: 1.3
        },
        Rectangle {
            x: 825, y: 220
            width: 150, height: 20
            fill: Color.BLACK
        },
        Text {
            font : Font {size: 18}
            x: 845, y: 235
            content: "De regels"
            fill: Color.WHITE
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: You will hardly find anybody who still remembers that ancient version of JavaFX. Are you sure you mean 1.0?

Comment: Yes (at least, our teachter said it was 1.0), it's for a school assingment and we had to download a virtual computer with WindowsXP to use it.

Comment: I just found out it's probbably 1.6, but that's still ancient.

Comment: I'm curious to know why your teacher has you using JavaFX 1.6? The current version is JavaFX 11.0.2 (with a jump between 2 and 8) and JavaFX 12 is around the corner. Are you using JavaFX Script (removed in JavaFX 2) or something?

Comment: whatever the version: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, then nobody would have to guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I am going to assume that your instructor is mistaken on the version
>   of JavaFX they have you using. If they are correct, these instructions may not work for you (as I am not familiar with steam-powered Java)...**

The likely cause of your issue is that the `String` being used to set the `Label`'s `textProperty` is longer than the `Label` is able to display. Without seeing your actual code, I have a couple of suggestions:

First of all, make sure that your `Label` is wrapping its text:

`label.setWrapText(true);`

Secondly, you should make sure that the `Label` is wrapped in a layout container that can handle a node that grows (not always necessary, but recommended). My recommendation is a `VBox`:

```
VBox vBox = new VBox(label);
```

---

Again, there is some assumption here on the version of JavaFX you're actually using, but you could try this simple example to see if it works for you:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox vBox = new VBox(5);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label label = new Label();

        // Let's add some very long text to our Label
        label.setText("This is long text. It doesn't mean much because I am just writing things to make it long. Yes, I am that clever. Don't you just love this? Neither do I!");

        // Make sure the Label is setup to wrap text when it reaches the end of its boundaries
        label.setWrapText(true);

        // Add the Label to our VBox
        vBox.getChildren().add(label);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

> **Result:**

[image: screenshot 1]

---

To confirm that `label.setWrapText(true);` actually makes a difference, here's the result of the above code **without** that line, complete with the elipses ("...") you're experiencing:

[image: screenshot 2]